# how to optimize (reduce) the latency in the verilog HDL code (hardware) generated by the MATLAB HDL CODER add-on from a given Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, verilog, simulink, hdl-coder

Thanks in advance,

I am having a simple Simulink model, that takes in a 32-bit number in the IEEE-754 format and adds the same number, which gives the output again in the 32-bit wide IEEE-754 format. I used MATLAB's HDL CODER add-on and generated the Verilog HDL code for the same. When I wrote a testbench for the same, I found the latency I get from this code is 100ns. But is there a way I can reduce this to even further, say some 10ns.

Below I am attaching the Simulink model I used to generate the Verilog HDL code, along with the generated Verilog files. Also, I am attaching a screenshot of the simulation in case you don't want to waste your time running the scripts

[image: Simulation of addition]

[Link to download the files](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/plyb36f28hyxm/Sum_Files)

Comment: You can not find the maximum operating frequency from simulation. 
You need to synthesize the code and find out from that what the maximum operating frequency is. Note that FPGA designers normally try to avoid floating point numbers as they are notoriously slow and use lots of resources.

Comment: Ok! Actually my point is how to use pipeline settings before conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my point is how to use pipeline settings before conversion

I am assuming that *"pipeline settings"* is a MATLAB HDL generator parameter.

Basically what you do is "try": use a pipeline setting and synthesize the code. If you have slack you can:

- Reduce the number of pipeline stages.

  or
- Increase the clock frequency.

(For negative slack you use the inverse methods)

Now here is where things get tricky:
Most of the time you can't really speed things up. A certain functionality needs a time to calculate. Some algorithms can be sped up by using more parallel resources but only up tot a limit. An adder is good example: you can have ripple carry, carry look-ahead and more advanced techniques, but **you can not speed up infinitely.** (Otherwise CPUs these days would be running at Terra Hz)

I suspect in the end you will find that it takes T time to do your IEEE-754 adder. That can be X clock cycles of an A MHz. clock or  Y clock cycles of B MHz. But X times A is about the same as Y times B.

What you can do is pump lots of calculations into your pipe so a new one comes out every clock cycle. But the latency will still be there.